# Custom iOS payload with Urban airship in PHP

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I am trying to send some custom data with the payload to iOS devices. I use the following code to successfully send pushes to all devices but I need to send some additional data. I couldn't find any documentation for urban airship and everything I tried just gives me errors.

Code:

```
     $contents = array();
     $contents['badge'] = "+1";
     $contents['alert'] = $message;
     $contents['sound'] = "cat.caf";
     $notification = array();
     $notification['ios'] = $contents;
     $platform = array();
     array_push($platform, "ios");

     $push = array("audience"=>"all", "notification"=>$notification, "device_types"=>$platform);

     $json = json_encode($push);

     $session = curl_init(PUSHURL);
     curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERPWD, APPKEY . ':' . PUSHSECRET);
     curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, True);
     curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
     curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, False);
     curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
     curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json', 'Accept: application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;'));
     $content = curl_exec($session);
```

Comment: What errors does it give you? Those errors will point you in the right direction. Also, please include what your payload looks like in your question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I came to this. In the 'contents' section of your code add this line:

```
$contents['extra'] = array("message"=>"another message");
```

This should enable you to send additional custom data along with your push.